# We used to send parameters to our WMS geoserver SQLViews by the viewparams field. But WMTS doesn't have this field

Tags: geoserver

`Geoserver` offers to use [parametrized SQL views](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html). Parameters are put in a *viewparams* field and it receives them as parameters for the SQL request.

However, we discovered that tiled WMS (WMTS) doesn't have that *viewparams* field.
How can we send our parameters ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that `WMTS` layers have for target to be cached by tools/components like `GeoWebCache`, while `WMS` ones are always ran by the `geoserver`.

A `WMTS` layer can be called in `WMS` mode, and then :

- If you need to use a parameter, put it in the SQL view, and call the layer with a `WMS` request, with the `viewparams` parameter,
- If you do not need to use a parameter, call it through `WMTS` and then futher calls might benefits from the contents being recovered from cache.